# Error 422 con FastAPI: no me pilla el campo como opcional

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, fastapi

Tengo una api con FastAPI y tengo una clase Task la cual su id es opcional, pero no lo pilla como tal. Paso el modelo:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional
from bson import ObjectId


class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return str(v)


class Task(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias="_id")
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    completed: bool = False

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
        populate_by_field_name = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

Conecto a mi base de datos de mongoDB con la libreria motor de esta forma y hago el insert:

```
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from models import Task

client = AsyncIOMotorClient('mongodb://localhost')
database = client.taskdatabase
collection = database.task

async def create_task(task):
    new_task = await collection.insert_one(task)
    created_task = await collection.find_one({"_id": new_task.inserted_id})
    return created_task
```

Y aquí es donde instancio la ruta para llamarla:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from database import get_all_tasks, create_task
from models import Task

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/api/tasks", response_model=Task)
async def save_task(task: Task):
    response = await create_task(task.dict())
    if response:
        return response

    raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, "Something went wrong")
```

Y este es el error que me devuelve mi servidor al hacer la llamada con el postman:

```
Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "_id"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "title": "some title",
        "description": "some description",
        "completed": true
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Las librerías que tiene mi servidor son: FastAPI, motor y uvicorn por si ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás haciendo el post? Además, creería (no estoy segura de) que te falta `Body(...)` en el método _save_task_ `(task: Task = Body(...)):`.